# OS X ZSH UTF-8 <xxxx> characters when autocomplete

Tags: macos, utf-8, terminal, zsh

If a name of file contains czech character and I try to autocomplete the name, it gets converted to <xxxx> character

e.g.

```
| => ls -l ~/Documents/App[_here I hit TAB_]lis<030c>te<030c> 
total 276
-rw-r--r--@ 1 malekjir  staff  279452 20 lis 23:28 001-Tunelování-rozsahů-ip-adres.pages
```

which name is

```
| => ls -ld ~/Documents/App*
drwxr-xr-x  3 malekjir  staff  102 20 lis 23:28 /Users/malekjir/Documents/Appliště
```

I use `zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)` on `OS X 10.10`,

```
| => locale
LANG="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

| => echo $LANG
cs_CZ.UTF-8
```

In bash, the autocomplete is OK

```
| => bash
| %n@%M [%d] 
| => ls -l ~/Documents/App[_here I hit TAB_]liště/
```

When I log as root, which env was not altered, I get this

```
root# ~malekjir/Documents/App[_here I hit TAB_]lis$'\314'$'\214'te$'\314'$'\214'/
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi - this really isn't programming related. You'd have better luck on `superuser.com` (or perhaps `apple.stackexchange.com` - but I feel this is more of a `zsh` problem rather than something specific to osx). I have flagged this for migration.